# Is it ok to run `emacs --fg-daemon` and `emacs --bg-daemon` at the same time?

Tags: daemon

I am trying to run `GNU Emacs 29.0.50` in `macOS`. The way install it as follows:

```
brew reinstall emacs-head@29 --with-cocoa --with-native-comp
```

---

I have observe that `Emacs --fg-daemon` and `Emacs --bg-daemon` processes are running at the same time.

```bash
$ ps auxww | grep Emacs
alper  14481 100.0  0.4 34400312  71716   ??  R     2:48PM   0:02.35 /usr/local/Cellar/emacs-head@29/29.0.50_1/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs --fg-daemon
alper  12776   0.0  1.3 34563148 211120   ??  SNs   2:46PM   0:12.07 /usr/local/Cellar/emacs-head@29/29.0.50_1/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs --bg-daemon=\0123,4\012
```

The way I started emacs: `(&>/dev/null emacsclient -qut &)`

I was wondering is it fine that both `Emacs --fg-daemon` and `Emacs --bg-daemon` are running at the same time and do they cause extra cpu usage or both of them referring to the same daemon process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overcome this I had to install emacs from source-code and downgrade emacs version to 28. This also fixes high cpu usage I was having.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

cp ~/personalize/emacs.el ~/.emacs
mkdir -p ~/git
cd ~/git
git clone --depth 1 --branch emacs-28 git://git.savannah.gnu.org/emacs.git
cd emacs
./autogen.sh
./configure --with-native-compilation --with-json --with-modules --with-xpm \
            --with-harfbuzz --with-compress-install --with-threads \
            --with-included-regex --with-x-toolkit=lucid --with-zlib \
            --with-jpeg --with-png --with-imagemagick --with-tiff --with-gnutls \
            --with-xft --with-xml2 --with-mailutils CPPFLAGS='-fgnu89-inline'
make -j$(nproc)
sudo mkdir -p /opt/ss
sudo rm -f /opt/ss/*
rm -f ~/.emacs.elc >/dev/null 2>&1
rm -rf ~/.emacs.d/elpa
rm -rf ~/.emacs.d/eln-cache
rm -rf ~/var
sudo ln -s ~/git/emacs/lib-src/emacsclient /opt/ss/
sudo ln -s ~/git/emacs/src/emacs /opt/ss/
(&>/dev/null /opt/ss/emacsclient -cqut &)
```